# Writing a specific listview tag property to a text file

Tags: vb.net

The code below originally just removed a user from a listview based on the name. I want to add the ability to first write the listview's tag property to a text file first but I'm confused about how I should specify the listview item I want the tag from before removing it. Can someone advise me? Thanks.

```
Public Sub RemoveUser(ByVal name As Object)
    If _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.InvokeRequired Then
        _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.Invoke(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf RemoveUser), name)
    Else
        Dim lvi As ListViewItem = GetListViewItemsIndex(DirectCast(name, String))
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = Application.StartupPath & "\accounts\" & DirectCast(name, String)
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
        objWriter.Write("This is where I need to call the tag to write.")
        objWriter.Close()
        _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.Items.Remove(lvi)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a corrected version of your `Sub` performing the actions you want:

```
Public Sub RemoveUser(ByVal name As Object)
    If _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.InvokeRequired Then
        _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.Invoke(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf RemoveUser), name)
    Else
        Dim lvi As ListViewItem = _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.FindItemWithText(DirectCast(name, String))
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = Application.StartupPath & "\accounts\" & DirectCast(name, String)
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
        objWriter.Write(lvi.Tag)
        objWriter.Close()
        _mainView.lvwChannelUsers.Items.Remove(lvi)
    End If
End Sub
```